# How to catch all different kind of errors from Firebase Storage in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I would like to be able to catch and respond according to specific errors from `firebase_storage` in my Flutter app.

Here is what i would like to do:

```
UploadTask task = FirebaseStorage.instance.reference().putFile("filePath");
task.catchError((FirebaseStorageException exception) {
  switch (exception.state) {
    case FirebaseStorageExceptionState.unknown:
       break;
    case FirebaseStorageExceptionState.canceled:
       break;
    ...
  }
})
```

For now I'm doing the catch this way according to the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#file-uploads):

```
task.catchError((FirebaseException error) {
  if (error.code == "canceled") {
    ...
  }
})
```

Which is definitely not a good way to go because i don't know all of the `String` and they may changed in the future...

Is there any way to be able to do this?